In Bleach, What is Nelliel's Aspect of Death?
What is Nel's Aspect of Death?
Is it Sacrifice or Lamentation?
According to this link, it's Sacrifice (which is stated by Tite Kubo).

But on this link, her aspect of death is Lamentation.

Which one is it?

As Kubo Tite mentioned, Neliel's aspect of death is sacrifice. Aizen gave all identical aspect of death per number, as such Luppi Antenor (prior #6) and Grimmjow Jaegerjaquez (present #6) are sharing same aspect of death of Destruction.
The way how #3 Espadas (both Neliel and Halibel) were given their aspect of death: sacrifice is quite same too.
Halibel managed to defeat the bastrode (if I spelled correctly) by sacrificing herself (but later that bastrode was killed thanks to the help of Aizen) after her three Fraccions were defeated.
Neliel was sacrificed by Noitra transformed into child form after her mask was broken. It could be said that her death is sacrifice for saving two Fraccions not being killed further after wounded too much by Noitra too.
